# iptables doesn't recognize --log-prefix

Tags: iptables, logging

I'm having difficulty getting iptables to log.  Here are the relevant commands:

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -N LOG_DROP
/usr/sbin/iptables -A LOG_DROP -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables drop: " --log-level 7
/usr/sbin/iptables -A LOG_DROP -j DROP
```

Entering these commands, results in:

> iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "--log-prefix"

I believe the following modules are important, so they're active in my kernel:

```
`nf_log_common
 nf_log_ipv4
 nf_log_ipv6`
```

Any suggestions for solving this problem?

Comment: Whatt os/distro & if applicable hypervisor.

Comment: gentoo, xen, kernel 4.1.15

Answer (score 0):

I had to run all commands with root privileges (`sudo`). *Obviously iptables command executed by user didn't know about the channel created by root.*

Answer (score 0):

In Centos 7
you can use the following commands

```
iptables -N SIPDOS

mkdir -p /var/log/firewall/

touch /var/log/firewall/iptables.log

chmod 600 /var/log/firewall/iptables.log

chown root:adm /var/log/firewall/iptables.log

touch /etc/rsyslog.d/firewall.conf

echo -e ":msg, contains, «iptables: » -/var/log/firewall/iptables.log\n& ~ " >>/etc/rsyslog.d/firewall.conf

touch /etc/logrotate.d/firewall

echo -e "/var/log/firewall/iptables.log\n{\nrotate 7\ndaily\nsize 10M\ndateext\nmissingok\ncreate 600 root adm\nnotifempty\ncompress\ndelaycompress\npostrotate\ninvoke-rc.d rsyslog reload > /dev/null\nendscript\n} " >>/etc/logrotate.d/firewall

service rsyslog restart

iptables -A SIPDOS -j LOG --log-prefix "firewall-sipdos:" --log-level 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out whether your device’s kernel supports such a target:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG
```

reference: https://forum.sailfishos.org/t/iptables-log-target-missing/4537

Answer (score -1):

You miss a kernel module:

```
modprobe nfnetlink_log
```